# Attempting to make a vowel counter in Python, Y value is counting twice the first time?

Tags: python

First of all I know there are simpler (and better) ways to do this, I'm very new to this. 
When I run this, it works fine, except that the first time it counts a Y, it adds 2. If I start with `y=-1` everything comes out correct. What is causing this?

```
word=raw_input("Input your word>")
a=0
e=0
i=0
o=0
u=0
y=0

letternumber=len(word)
while letternumber>=0:
    letternumber=letternumber-1
    if word[int(letternumber)].lower() == "a":
        a=a+1
    elif word[int(letternumber)].lower() == "e":
        e=e+1
    elif word[int(letternumber)].lower() == "i":
        i=i+1
    elif word[int(letternumber)].lower() == "o":
        o=o+1
    elif word[int(letternumber)].lower() == "u":
        u=u+1
    elif word[int(letternumber)].lower() == "y":
        y=y+1
else:

    print str(a) + str(e) + str(i) + str(o) + str(u) + str(y)
```

Comment: FYI - just tried it - works for me!

Comment: What is the input word you are testing with?

Comment: I expect the problem is that the last letter of the string gets processed twice: once in the loop in which `letternumber` initially is `len(word)` and then gets decremented to `len(word)-1`, and then again in the loop in which `letternumber` initially is `0` and then gets decremented to `-1`.

Comment: You also might like to look at the output in the case where some vowel appears 10 or more times.

Comment: @steve Yea, this isn't the idea way to show the output, it was more something I threw on to see if it would work. Good point though, thanks.

Comment: @Dejarr: in that case for future reference, do `print a, e, i, o, u, y` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop logic is broken. Change `letternumber>=0:` to `letternumber>0:` because in your loop you decrement `letternumber` before checking the position in the word. You end up checking `word` at -1 or the last letter again (so words ending in a vowel will be counted twice)

Comment: Since it decrements before checking, it will also not count the vowel if it is the first character of the string.

Comment: @Wondercricket it will check every letter and the last letter twice

Comment: @depperm I see, thanks so much! Makes sense, not sure how I didn't see that. =)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are right, you need `letternumber > 0`.  But your code's not very Pythonic.

A slightly better fix would be use a "for" loop:

```
for letternumber in range(len(word)):
    if word[letternumber].lower() == "a":
        ... etc
```

(That solution, and all the other ones I'm going to show, go through the word in order instead of backwards, but that doesn't really matter).

A much better fix would be to use a "for" loop across the word, since you don't really need the index into the word.  You can also convert to lowercase once at the start of the loop, rather than 6 times per letter:

```
word=raw_input("Input your word>")
a=0
e=0
i=0
o=0
u=0
y=0

for letter in word.lower():
    if letter == "a":
        a=a+1
    elif letter == "e":
        e=e+1
    elif letter == "i":
        i=i+1
    elif letter == "o":
        o=o+1
    elif letter == "u":
        u=u+1
    elif letter == "y":
        y=y+1

print str(a) + str(e) + str(i) + str(o) + str(u) + str(y)
```

The best fix, which simplifies it a lot, is to use the standard library's counter (new in Python 2.7):

```
from collections import Counter

word = raw_input("Input your word>")
counts = Counter(word.lower())
a = counts['a']
e = counts['e']
i = counts['i']
o = counts['o']
u = counts['u']
y = counts['y']
print str(a) + str(e) + str(i) + str(o) + str(u) + str(y)
```

Comment: Would it be more *Pythonic* to use a loop in order to count and display each vowel?

Comment: @A.I. That would be a reasonable approach, yep.  Alternatively, if what you want to do is convert "Apple sauce" to "Aeaue", then you can use the one-liner `s = ''.join(ch for ch in word if ch.lower() in 'aeiouy')`

Answer (score 0):

If you throw in a 'letter position' counter, you can see the problem:

```
while letternumber >=0:
    print letternumber
```

The script counts along the index of characters in the string to the '0' position, starting at 'length' - you end up with an extra loop corresponding to the index at position 'length' (which is one more than the last position of the string) - this is what @Steve Jessop is pointing out. Your program ends up counting twice if the last letter is a vowel (I tested with 'apple', for example, and it double counts the 'e').

If you set your counter to be:

```
letternumber = len(word) - 1
```

then everything behaves itself.

changing the while loop (above) also works.